# stuck on this integration problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, initial-value-problems

Solve the following IVP

$$ \dot y = y - t $$

where $t_0 = 1$  and $y(t_0) = y(1) = 1$.

---

What I did is this:

Let $u = y-t$

Therefore  $ \frac{du}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dt} -1$

Hence, differential equation becomes

$\frac{du}{dt} +1 = u$

To integrate this by separation of variables,

$\frac{du}{u-1} = dt$

Hence,

$$ \int_{0}^{u} \frac{du}{u-1} = \int_{1}^{t} d t $$

where lower limit of $u = y(t=1) - t(0) = 1-1 = 0$ and lower limit of $t$ is $t_0 = 1.$

After integration,

$\log_e(u-1) \rvert_0^u = t-1$

$\log_e(u-1) - log_e(0-1) = t-1$

But $\log_e(-1)$ is not defined.

So how do I proceed further?

Comment: Your substitution doesn't work since your second equation is not equivalent to the first one...

Comment: Use indefnite integrals (i.e., anti-dervatives). Your limits of integration are not correct.

Comment: @geetha290krm: Will you please explain in detail ?

Comment: $log_e(u-1)=t+C$. Find $C$.

Comment: @geetha290krm: Initial conditions i.e. y=1 and when t=1 are given in the book. When new variable u is used, its lower limit will be u = y- t = 1-1 = 0 and upper limit will be u, since this is initial value problem. What is wrong in this ?

Answer (score 1):

For this type of ODE (by "this type" I mean that the ODE is equivalent to getting a difference of $y$ and $y'$ on one side of the ODE) you can also use the technique one uses to derive the formula for the variation of constants formula. It is
\begin{align}
y'=y-t\Leftrightarrow y'-y=-t.
\end{align}
Multiply the ODE by $e^{-t}$ which gives
\begin{align}
y'(t)e^{-t}-y(t)e^{-t}=-te^{-t}.
\end{align}
Why did we multiply the ODE by $e^{-t}$? Because now the term on the left hand side can be written as a derivative of a product. Indeed it is
\begin{align}
y'(t)e^{-t}-y(t)e^{-t}= \frac{d}{dt}(y(t)e^{-t}).
\end{align}
So you have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(y(t)e^{-t})=-te^{-t}.
\end{align}
Now you can integrate the equation and use your initial condition. I leave the computation as an exercise.

Comment: When I integrate last equation, on LHS , I get just $y(t)exp^(-t)$, since integration and differentiation processes nullify each other. Correct ? And on RHS, I get (using product rule),$ (1+t)exp^(-t)$. Correct ? (Initial condition yet to be used.)

Comment: @atom I think you miss $-e^{-1}$ on RHS. You can check that your if you multiply by $e^{-t}$ your solution would be $y(t)=(1+t)$. You can always check your calculation by plugging in the initial condition which fails for your solution. Just for you to check $y(t)=t+1-e^{t-1}$ is the solution.